# Using protocol and delegation in SWIFT

Tags: swift, delegates, uicollectionview, protocols

I am trying to pass information over from a collection view cell to another view controller, then dismiss the view controller. I am trying to do this with delegation as I think this is the only way, so far I have set up my protocol like so:

```
@objc protocol CollectionViewImageDelegate {
   optional func selectedCell(row: NSIndexPath, data: UIImage) 
}
```

I have added the property:

```
var delegate : CollectionViewImageDelegate?
```

and then called it in the `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) { 

        let imageData = self.sources[indexPath.row] 
        self.delegate?.selectedCell?(indexPath, data: imageData) 

        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Then how do I call it other View Controller so far I have done:

```
class ProfileViewController: UIViewController, CollectionViewImageDelegate {

var colViewImage : CollectionViewVC
```

in the view did load:

```
colViewImage.delegate = self
```

and this but nothing happens:

```
func selectedCell(row: NSIndexPath, data: UIImage) {
    println(data) //Nothing prints
}
```

Nothing is printing I don't know why?
I'm new to protocol and delegates etc and can't seem to work out why it isnt passing over the image??

Thanks

Comment: Is `image` an actual class (not instance) you have defined? Maybe you want to use `UIImage` instead of `image` in your protocol?

Comment: Yes thanks that was it, new I was close. Although I how do I now pass that date selected over to my other view controller, I have changed my question slightly and added to it.

Comment: Is there a chance this could not be working because I am dismissing the View Controller instead of segue?

Answer (score 0):

Your CollectionViewController is calling this selectedCell method but you haven't linked the delegate yet.

Make your other ViewController conform to collectionViewImageDelegate (which should conventionally be spelled with a capital C) and implement your method selectedCell in it.

Set the ViewController as delegate of the CollectionViewController.

Also, change `self.delegate?.selectedCell!(indexPath, data: imageData)` into `self.delegate?.selectedCell?(indexPath, data: imageData)` to call the optional method selectedCell only if it was implemented by the delegate.

Comment: Thanks, although thats exactly the bit I am struggling with doing as I don't know how to do it. I have set up a reference to the other VC like so: var VC2 = ViewController2(). and then what? I have tried to do VC2.delegate = self in my viewDidLoad but the option does not come up? I can't figure it out

Comment: You need to give some more information.It would also help if you name your classes more descriptively according to what their purpose is. ViewController2 doesn't really tell you what it does. Something like ImagePickerCollectionViewController would be better.

Comment: I have changed my code to exactly how it is. ViewController 2 I was refrencing to the collectionView controller I am trying to pass the information from into ViewController 1

Comment: All my code should now be correct although that println in the function is still not print I don't know why?